# Javascript background color on a timer?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner with javascript. I've searched and I don't understand why this javascript code code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  window.onload = function start(){

    changeBGColor();
  }

  function changeBGColor() {
    var colors = ["#ffccff", "#6666ff", "#ff5050", "#88ff4d"];
      var index = 0;
    window.setInterval(function() {
      if (index >= colors.length)
        index = 0; // reset back to first color
      $("body").css("background-color", colors[index]);
      index++;
    }, 1000);
  }

});
```

isn't changing the body of the webpage every second. I'm at a loss.

Comment: It is working as expected. Check this [**LINK**](https://jsfiddle.net/qc5g3n61/)

Comment: Give the link of codepen

Comment: window.onload is not necessary within. ready()

Comment: Remove either `$(document).ready()` or `window.onload`. Personally I'd remove `window.onload`

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason it only works when I feed changeBGColor directly into window.onload. And Your right, I don't need `window.onload` within `$(document.ready()`

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because it is not a plain JavaScript Code.

It is a [jQuery](https://www.jquery.com) code and you need to include the jQuery library in your html from jQuery CDN

Add the below code to include it

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using codepen with jquery already in it.